# Connecting to a web service with SilverLight

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have been looking online for a simple way to call a web service through silverlight application and cant decide how to do it. What would be the simplest way to connect to this website: http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx and return an xml with the specified zip code (I have this done using AJAX already i just want to try and get it working using silverlight as an alternative). Any help is very much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm.. It is so easy. In your Silverligt project click on "Reference" select "Add Service Reference.." and add wsdl of weather service (http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?WSDL). The Visual Studio 11 Beta generates WCF proxy with [basicHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.aspx). And use it as any service.

UODATE: Add next reference

```
using SilverlightApplication1.ServiceReference1;
```

And implementation.

```
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var weather = new WeatherSoapClient();
            weather.GetWeatherInformationCompleted
                += new EventHandler<GetWeatherInformationCompletedEventArgs>(OnGetWeatherInformationCompleted);
            weather.GetWeatherInformationAsync();
        }

        private void OnGetWeatherInformationCompleted(object sender, GetWeatherInformationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Get data from e.Result
        }
```

To my mind you should read something about web services and WCF.

Comment: I have done that but im not sure how to make the calls and how to return the info.

Comment: Am i putting the C# code on the server side? and how do i pass the parameter? Thanks a ton!

Comment: If it is your server you can. You can pass ZIP code not more for current implementation of service.